# Excel is running out memory when copying rows with .rows(y).value = .rows(x).value

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I want to copy certain rows over to another worksheet. 
For this I am using these lines in a loop:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    Select Case ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Case "00"
        Case "01"
        Case "02"
        Case "03"
        Case Else
            wsNew.Rows(rowCounter).Value = ws.Rows(i).Value
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    End Select
Next i
```

Before this is a big select statement to only copy certain rows.
ws is my original worksheet,
wsNew is my new worksheet and 
rowCounter is just a helper to know how many I filled in wsNew
lRow is the number of rows in my sheet,

I just want to have the rows that fall into the else copied to the new sheet.

Since I only do .Value = .Value I don't really understand how it uses ram at all, since I thought that .Value = .Value is literally only using ram for that line and gets immediately garbage collected.

The code works with i from 2 to 100, but the data I am working with has ~23000 rows. And after about 21000 rows I run out of ram for 32bit excel.

Using 64bit excel is not an option atm.

Comment: what are i, lRow, and rowCounter declared as?

Comment: show your _"big select statement"_ and  how you make the copy of _"certain rows."_

Comment: Don't copy the whole row - copy only to the last column.

Comment: I added my select statement, I still don't understand how the wsNew.Rows(rowCounter).Value = ws.Rows(i).Value is using any ram at all. Without that line it works flawlessly without using much more ram than just having the workbook open.

Comment: Don't copy/paste inside a loop. Use a filter or union so you can copy/paste all at once.

Comment: If you are not acting on your first 4 cases you can add them to one line: `Case "00", "01", "02", "03"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost 100% certain you don't need to copy the entire excel row - including all possible columns, even blank ones.

Give this a shot:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    Select Case ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        Case "00"
        Case "01"
        Case "02"
        Case "03"
        Case Else
            Dim lastColumn as Long
            lastColumn = ws.Cells(i,ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            wsNew.Cells(rowCounter,1).Resize(1,lastColumn).Value = ws.Cells(i,1).Resize(1,lastColumn).Value
            rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
    End Select
Next i
```

Comment: Wow, in my naivety I thought Excel would only copy the used cells. Well thank you, that solved it.

Comment: @Barbarian772 - great. glad it worked. just so you know, it's even faster more efficient to load all the values into a range - using union inside the loop - then write the range once at the end. It's a little more code to write, but that's definitely the way to go in most extreme cases.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Autofilter()` to make a one-shot copy-paste:

```
Dim unWantedRng As Range
With ws
    With .Range("Z1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<-- change "Z" to whatever column name has the last one of yuor database
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("00", "01", "02", "03"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Set unWantedRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

        unWantedRng.EntireRow.RowHeight = 0

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A1")
        rowCounter = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        unWantedRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also this code, please. It should be very fast:

```
Sub testRowsCopyOtherSheet()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngUR As Range
 Dim i As Long, lRow As Long
 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
 Set wsNew = Worksheets("Sheet25")'use here your sheet (I used it for testing)
 Set rngUR = ws.UsedRange
 lRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

 For i = 2 To lRow
    Select Case ws.Cells(i, 1).value
        Case "00"
        Case "01"
        Case "02"
        Case "03"
        Case Else
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then                    
                Set rng = Union(rng, Intersect(rngUR, ws.Rows(i)))
            Else
                Set rng = Intersect(rngUR, ws.Rows(i))
            End If
    End Select
 Next i
 wsNew.Range("A1").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).value = rng.value
End Sub
```

If not necessary to copy in "A1", it is easy to be adapted...